# Get Users' profile data from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch user profile data using Facebook graph API. I can search by name with search endpoint. I can receive a list of users with name and Id, but I can't get any *additional* information about them, even if it is opened and I can see it on a user's Facebook page. How is it possible to retrieve other user's profile data (**not profile of authorized user**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get additional data if that user authorizes your App. Everything else would be a privacy issue. It does not matter if the data is available on facebook.com, Apps can´t access a user profile without authorization.